# columns to rows maintaining userid

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have columns that look like this:

```
UserID    col1    col2    col3    col4
---------------------------------------
233432    45.2    34.2    ''      0.52
```

I want it to look like this:

```
UserID    colID    value
-------------------------
233432    col1     45.2
233432    col2     34.2
233432    col3     ''
233432    col4     0.52
```

I found this link below:

[column to row in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956345/column-to-row-in-sql-server)

but it doesn't really answer the question I have.my question.  I am using Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select UserID,'col1',col1 as 'value' from mytable
union
Select UserID,'col2',col2 from mytable
union
Select UserID,'col3',col3 from mytable
union
Select UserID,'col4',col4 from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use CROSS APPLY with VALUES to UNPIVOT the data:

```
select t.userid,
  c.colid,
  c.value
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values
  ('col1', col1),
  ('col2', col2),
  ('col3', col3),
  ('col4', col4)
) c (colid, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78597/2)